# How do I change a switched outlet with 2 sets of wires to a half hot outlet?

Tags: receptacle

I have 2 sets of wiring in the outlet box the 2 black wires are tied together the 2 white wires are   connected to the neutral side of the outlet and the 1 red wire is connected to the hot side of the outlet How do I make this a half hot outlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Red wire should be switched hot.

Blacks should be hot.

Turn off power for the outlet at the breaker, make sure power is dead at the outlet and switch.

Should be a tab connecting both hot screws on outlet.

Remove tab and use a short piece of black wire(same gauge) and pigtail it to the two blacks and connect to second hot screw of the outlet.

Check that the red wire is switched hot, by checking if switch controls power to it.